# Does a xacro exist for the kinect

Tags: kinect, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To date, I have put together two robot systems that use a kinect sensor.  My current approach is to copy and paste the kinect urdf into each of the system urdf's (this is obviously prone to errors).  It seems to me that the kinect is complex enough and used by enough people that a common xacro would be useful.  Does anybody know if there is a xacro for the kinect sensor itself.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28120/does-a-xacro-exist-for-the-kinect/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the turtlebot kinect xacro. works fine for me so far.
turtlebot_description/urdf/turtlebot_kinect.urdf.xacro

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3